# Maintainig state of child activities in TabGroupActivity

Tags: android, tabs, tabactivity, activitygroup

I have followed [this](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html) tutorial for my application.

I have:
Tab 1: Tabgroupactivity1>(startchildactivity)MainActivty>(startchildactivity)ListActivity>(startchildactivity)DetailActivity

similarly I have other two tabs.

The thing is that when i Return from any of the following activity to previous one it(previous one) gets restarted.

I too have tried to startchild activity with SINGLE_TOP and SINGLE_TASK but in this **only once I can go through the flow**

**second time it does not call following(next/child) activity**

So How can i maintain current activty state while it calls for child activity and return ??

I am Using following intent onclick of listactivty:

```
Intent myintent = new Intent(getParent(),Second.class);
myintent.putExtra("id",favadapter.getItem(position).id.toString());
TabGroupActivity parentFav = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
parentFav.startChildActivity("FavActivity", myintent);
```

Comment: Paste your code for proper understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Actually TabGroupActivity have a problem in android 2.1 and 2.2 , the activities not properly removed from stack causes our instance to restart every time.

To overcome that issue we use SINGLE_TOP and SINGLE_TASK, even it cause another problem only one instance run not for second time because in child finish we did like this,

```
Intent lastIntent = manager.getActivity(lastId).getIntent();
        Window newWindow = manager.startActivity(lastId, lastIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP));
        setContentView(newWindow.getDecorView());
```

means it remove all lastID intent and bring the latest one, because your lastId (which is used while starting activity `.startChildActivity("FavActivity", myintent);` ) is same for multiple instance.

In order to allow your child activity to run second time or for multiple instance use **Dynamic intent ID** to launch child activity.

For example,

```
Intent myintent = new Intent(getParent(),Second.class);
myintent.putExtra("id",favadapter.getItem(position).id.toString());
TabGroupActivity parentFav = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
parentFav.startChildActivity("FavActivity"+System.currentTimemillis(), myintent);
```

Comment: I have used this issue exactly a month before:

  String newId = Id+""+Math.random()*1000;
    Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(newId,intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)); 

sometimes this too gives me blank screens for large stacks.:(